# Converting between timezones even when the same changes the date (UTC to UTC)

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, jodatime

I've been puzzled why the following code results in a change of my date from 25th to 24th

```
SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
DateTimeZone customerZone = DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
DateTimeZone serverZone = DateTimeZone.UTC;

Date date = sd.parse("25/05/2014");

DateTime source = new DateTime(date).withZone(customerZone).withHourOfDay(5);

LocalDateTime ldate = new LocalDateTime(source, serverZone);
System.out.println(ldate.toDate()); //expected to be Sat May 25 05:00:00
```

Result 
    "Sat May 24 05:00:00 SAST 2014"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't set a time zone for the `SimpleDateFormat`, so it's defaulting to your environment's time zone, which I am guessing is `"Africa/Johannesburg"`, since you have SAST in your result.

So when you do this part:

```
SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date = sd.parse("25/05/2014");
```

The `date` object will be midnight in SAST, which is 10PM the prior evening in UTC.  The rest follows from there, since you're working with UTC from that point forward.

Also, at the very end, you call `toDate`, which results in a `Date` object.  When you output that, again the local time zone is influencing the result.

You could consider calling `setTimeZone` on the `SimpleDateFormat` object.  That will at least get the beginning part right.  But you should also then use the `format` method to output the final string.

However, a better solution would be to use [JodaTime's `DateTimeFormatter`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) instead.  Then you won't have to use `SimpleDateFormat` or `Date` at all.

Comment: Yes, after some time of struggle I figured that out. You are correct. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

I think what happens is that 25/05/2014 00:00:00 in South Africa is seen as 24/5, 10 p.m., in the UTC customer time zone. Finally the hour is set to 5 a.m.

Answer (score 1):

The [answer by Matt Johnson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24345265/642706) is correct. When you omit a time zone, the JVM's default time zone is applied. I suggest *always* specifying a time zone rather than rely on implicit default, even if done by explicitly calling `getDefault()`.

## Pure Joda-Time

FYI, here is some example code for a better way to do this job. This way uses only [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). Mixing Joda-Time and java.util.Date/Calendar leads to confusion and pain, as your Questions shows. Furthermore, the java.util.Date, .Calendar, and SimpleDateFormat classes are notoriously troublesome and should be avoided.

By the way, no need for that call to getTimeZone and passing a TimeZone object. Joda-Time has a built-in constant for UTC: `DateTimeZone.UTC`.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "dd/MM/yyyy" ); // Usually I specify a Locale as well. But in this case, no need (no names of days or months).
DateTimeZone customerTimeZone = DateTimeZone.UTC;

String input = "25/05/2014";
DateTime customerDateTime = formatter.withZone( customerTimeZone ).parseDateTime( input );

DateTime customerDateTimeAtFive = customerDateTime.withHourOfDay( 5 );  // Using customerTimeZone.
```

Not sure why you are purposely losing time zone info by converting to LocalDateTime. There is no need to lose time zone if the goal is handling date-time values in UTC on the server. The server-side code should be using DateTime objects explicitly assigned to a time zone of UTC. You can adjust time zones this way:

```
DateTime serverDateTime = customerDateTimeAtFive.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC );
```

But anyways, if you insist (same as code in the Question)…

```
DateTimeZone serverTimeZone = DateTimeZone.UTC;
LocalDateTime localDateTime = new LocalDateTime( customerDateTimeAtFive, serverTimeZone ); // I don't see the point of using LocalDateTime, but here goes anyways.
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "customerTimeZone: " + customerTimeZone );
System.out.println( "input: " + input );
System.out.println( "customerDateTime: " + customerDateTime );
System.out.println( "customerDateTimeAtFive: " + customerDateTimeAtFive );
System.out.println( "serverDateTime: " + serverDateTime );
System.out.println( "serverTimeZone: " + serverTimeZone );
System.out.println( "localDateTime: " + localDateTime );
```

When run.

```
customerTimeZone: UTC
input: 25/05/2014
customerDateTime: 2014-05-25T00:00:00.000Z
customerDateTimeAtFive: 2014-05-25T05:00:00.000Z
serverDateTime: 2014-05-25T05:00:00.000Z
serverTimeZone: UTC
localDateTime: 2014-05-25T05:00:00.000
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. I should've included the full method in my question in order to answer your uncertainty on why I use LocalDateTime. The above code is part of a method which returns a java.util.Date. Hence the use of the LocalDateTime. The reason to use it because the DateTime.toDate() method returns a new Java date object constructed from the millis of the DateTime object. However the .withTimeZone() method doesn't change the milliseconds, resulting in the java.util.Date being returned being the original date without the applied timezone.